# How can I code for Multiple Level of Approval in asp.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am designing a program that needs multiple level of approval.

when an employee apply for leave 1 notification should go to his relevent Boss & if Boss approved it..
it should sent back a successfull message

Thanks & Wating for your valuable solution

Comment: This is StackOverflow. here we try to help programmers with concrete programming problems. We don't provide complete solutions. Please visit the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I totally agree with the comment leaved by @gert-arnold, what you're talking about is a "*Human Workflow System*", and generally a system like that is based on a *Persistent State Machine*: there are various ways to accomplish that technology speaking, and many frameworks and tools to do that, but this sure is not the kind of arguments to treat in StackOverflow